# Test if ssh fingerprints on server and in known_hosts match

Tags: ssh

I have a problem. I need bash script, which match ssh fingerprints in known_hosts and on remote server. Here is what I have:

```
keyFile=$(mktemp)
ssh-keyscan -H $ip > $keyFile 2> /dev/null
hashRemote=$(ssh-keygen -f $keyFile -H -F $ip | sed -n -r -e 's/^[^#][^ ]+ [^ ]+ ([^ ]+)$/\1/p')
hashLocal=$(ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts -H -F $ip | sed -n -r -e 's/^[^#][^ ]+ [^ ]+ ([^ ]+)$/\1/p')
rm $keyFile

echo $hashRemote
echo $hashLocal
```

Problem is, output is not consistent. Content od known_hosts depends on supported types of keys. So, output of ssh-keygen looks like this:

```
# Host 10.0.0.35 found: line 1 type RSA                                                          
|1|H24d9m0xG5zrw6QBkigVjarwTFw=|xpisuvwhtqsNkH0CJ6pYoB/y1G8= ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAAB
AQC1Ge/M8bA7nQsbMPy8JmFo6T3Ls2FXR01HyHoW5uwTeW3EoaD39IemRYmkDHLZwlQiLSSrw/kgkHATtQ4pqyg0o5mJoajmw
czUQ78Poavea60OYXJWLh12uZlRjyiu/tQXdHaBI3YwCNnP827t4guvJjpdOAsFgZqfuX9qERGPJMHj0YqRelanB9Za3Fueb9
QsT8wOe/wPCw2YwGapUndcUMoChmN2YRMjRk1JU4DPXiQ56+A2S9V4iP+drZfoK3c3tCdUOVUxCPEwqCraav+viSNq2odVL9F
79jIGxP43TqUcCyMcFU7vGEVshVu7gvUl7KKCMa0wu5pr+Z1X3zUn                                            
# Host 10.0.0.35 found: line 3 type ECDSA                                                        
|1|XdzrIRaJLfushc3efDRkNAJwqcQ=|UUyGx6z6I61mqMVRh/j/5+zs6eA= ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNo
YTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBLvteJqElWirJtA75IuDtvwKIbGfbvdCE+O/6bkFhj6oFlSVZqqecmm+MzRca
aLg30hLxLpO8bxwVxeVY62sDg8=
```

One type is RSA and one type is ECDSA. My question is, can i somehow match known_hosts and remote fingerprint? Thanks in advance...

Comment: The output from `ssh-keyscan` and the contents of a `known_hosts` file, after the first token or sometimes two, are the actual publickey, NOT a fingerprint. As long as you don't use broken and obsolete SSHv1, the format is always a word giving the type followed by a base64 blob. Remember a server/host usually has more than one type of publickey; if you want `ssh-keyscan` to get a particular type or list of types (e.g. for comparison) use `-t` per the man page -- but note this may not be the type, and key, used on a subsequent `ssh` connection.

Comment: In your case it looks like you have ecdsa-sha2-p256 in known_hosts so you probably want to use that as the type for ssh-keyscan.

Comment: Well, yes, I know I can force type, but we have many devices with many types and we don't know which device has which type. There is no way to read data from server/known_host in same format to compare? Or other way? Maybe some utility..

Comment: To find out what key types a 'device' (server) has, you must ask it; you can do `ssh-keyscan` with `-t` set to all keytypes supported in your version (see `ssh -Q key` if 6.5 up) and it will show what the server has and silently ignore the others. To find out what you have in a hashed known_hosts, find the lines with `ssh-keygen -F host` as you did and look at e.g. `awk '!/^#/{print $2}'` -- or `$(NF-1)` if you need to deal with lines containing options. Or `sed`, or `grep` if yours has `-Po` (PCRE matching and selective output), or `perl`, or even shell-builtin `read`; this is pretty basic.